# Install ffmpeg package inside docker container

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to install ffmpeg package inside dockerfile, but after that ffmpeg package was not installed.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

FROM openjdk:11-jdk
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/car-1.0.jar /home/car.jar
EXPOSE 8080:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/car.jar"]
```

If I enter inside docker container and run command:

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

package was successfuly installed and works.

With upper Dockerfile after finished build I typed:

```
whereis ffmpeg
```

and it was empty.

I also tried with static ffmpeg inside Dockerfile, but not works https://hub.docker.com/r/mwader/static-ffmpeg/

```
COPY --from=mwader/static-ffmpeg:4.3.1 /ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=mwader/static-ffmpeg:4.3.1 /ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Insall the executable in the child image as you already coping same executable from base images so what you are trying to achieve if you are coping the same  binary again?

Comment: I am trying to achive install ffmpeg package. apt-get install -y ffmpeg.
Do you have some example how to achive this inside docker with Dockerfile. @Adiii

ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/share/ffmpeg /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz

Comment: Run an Install command after `FROM openjdk:11-jdk` . In that way the second image will have it.